# Javascript html can't setAttribute <div> inside socket IO emit

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have something so strange Whenever I try this code it gives Error

```
socket.emit('TotalEarningsDays', '?', (data) => {
    console.log(data.TotalSunday);
    Test()
    
});
    
function Test(){
     var x = document.getElementById("TotalEarningsChart");

     x.setAttribute("data-series",'[[{"meta":"Sunday","value":"33"}, {"meta":"Monday","value":"87"},{"meta":"Tuesday","value":"470"},{"meta":"Wednesday","value":"580"},{"meta":"Thursday","value":"380"},{"meta":"Friday","value":"600"},{"meta":"Saturday","value":"707"}]]');
}
```

So this way it gives error says

```
VM4401:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
at Test (<anonymous>:26:9)
at r.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:19:1)
at r.onack (index.js:83)
at r.onpacket (index.js:83)
at r.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
at r.emit (index.js:83)
at r.ondecoded (index.js:83)
at a.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
at a.r.emit (index.js:83)
at a.add (index.js:83)
```

But if I call the Test function outside the socket Io Emit callback it works But I need it inside the emit so I can get the data
This way it does work

```
socket.emit('TotalEarningsDays', '?', (data) => {
     console.log(data.TotalSunday);
});
    
Test()

function Test(){
    var x = document.getElementById("TotalEarningsChart");
    
    x.setAttribute("data-series",'[[{"meta":"Sunday","value":"33"}, {"meta":"Monday","value":"87"},{"meta":"Tuesday","value":"470"},{"meta":"Wednesday","value":"580"},{"meta":"Thursday","value":"380"},{"meta":"Friday","value":"600"},{"meta":"Saturday","value":"707"}]]');
}
```

It reminds me of java main thread

Comment: Are you sure, that html block with ID `TotalEarningsChart` already exist on page when socket.emit happens?

Comment: 100% percent as I said the strange thing if I moved Test() outside the socket io emit it works so fine

Comment: Well, just to be 100% sure try to debug it somehow, for example try to log all your page HTML on the moment you do `emit`: `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML)`, and inspect result for existence of `TotalEarningsChart`...

Comment: Done and I didn't find it actually

Comment: If that's the case what should I do how to delay the emit?

Comment: I used setTimeout(Test, 10000) but still even after 10 sec it gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: Well, start from running your JS code on DOM ready (when all HTML is actually loaded): `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { initYourJSCode(); });`, where `initYourJSCode` is initial start function, i.e add all IO initialisations to this function, then test it... I'll add answer

Comment: I put all of the Socket IO emits and even connect it and it still gives this annoying error </3
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: Btw all other emits have elements to be changed all of them is great because they are <h4> but this one is <div> so maybe it has to do something with the element?

Comment: So if `h4` works and `div` not this means that `div` didn't exist on the moment it's called... Is this `div` hardcoded to html or generated dynamically by JS? If so - check that this `div` really generated and pushed to DOM before you call it in `emit`

Comment: I can now get the element div x inside the socket to emit but when I setAttribute it doesn't make the changes or effect I tried the .load method and tried to refresh it but still no way to make the effect even tho console.log shows the element as what I need exactly but it doesn't show on the page

Comment: And the div exists with the normal HTML no hardcodes or anything normally a div